# How to draw a manually drawn control inside a manually drawn control?

Tags: c#, onpaint

I have two controls in C# that I override `OnPaint()` to draw all the visuals myself.

I'd like to add one of those controls inside the other.

What do I put in my parent control's `OnPaint()` to call the child control's `OnPaint()`?

Comment: Shouldn't have to put anything in, Invalidating a parent control, should also invalidate it's children. Was you asking in advance of seeing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify winforms, but that seems very likely based on your question.

You are presumably calling Invalidate() or Refresh() depending upon your heart's desire.

Refresh() on a control should make the control and its children to repaint.

If you call Invalidate(true) on a control, the child controls should also receive the invalidate message. Invalidate() without the true parameters is not recursive.

Comment: Turns out I just forgot to do this.Controls.Add(myControl);